# How to uninstall MongoDB that was manually installed

Tags: mongodb, uninstallation

I installed MongoDB manually on the MongoDB website. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

I followed the instructions under "Install MongoDB Community Edition Manually".

How do I uninstall MongoDB completely? I have searched around and only found how to uninstall using Homebrew. I did not install MongoDB using Homebrew.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the [manual install steps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) in reverse order:

- [shutdown `mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes)
- remove your [data directory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#create-the-data-directory) (if you no longer want this)
- remove the [directory with the MongoDB binaries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#copy-the-extracted-archive-to-the-target-directory)
- remove the directory with the MongoDB binaries [from your shell `PATH`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#ensure-the-location-of-the-binaries-is-in-the-path-variable)

Other files that might have been created depending on how you ran MongoDB:

- there may be old log files to remove if you specified a [`--logpath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-logpath) outside your data directory
- there may be a `launchctl` script and configuration file to remove if you configured `mongod` to run as a service